# How do I make a local Yum cache for a different architecture/version/etc?

Tags: centos, yum

I have Centos running on an internet-connected computer, running i386 versions of some packages like MySQL.  I want to make a directory tree that I can put on removable media and put in a non-internet-connected computer which is running different software, and/or x86_64 versions of the same software.

Accomplishing this seems to have something to do with yum-utils and maybe /etc/rpm/platform, but I haven't found clear documentation on doing it without clobbering the currently installed software.

I especially haven't found any documentation on doing this on an ongoing basis--doing regular updates to the packages installed on the air-gapped computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for tips on creating a Yum cache, all you need to do is put the packages in a directory and run createrepo.  You may want to use the `-c` or `--cachedir` option to specify the cache directory on the removable media.

```
createrepo -c /mount/remotedrive/.cache /mount/remotedrive
```

If you're looking to install SPECIFIC architectures of the software available, you CAN specify the version number, i.e.:

```
yum install mysql-server.x86_64
```

or

```
yum install mysql-server.i386
```

Don't forget, also, that you can manually install one or more RPMs using the `rpm` utility:

```
rpm -ivh package.rpm
```

Hopefully this helps; your question isn't explicit about what you want, but this should point you in the right direction.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the start--I've run across those commands, but as far as I can tell they're not enough.  What I need is a version of "yum install mysql-server.x86_64" that will download all the dependencies and put them in a directory, but not install them. I'd rather not use rpm directly because it doesn't talk to yum, and I want to be able to do all my package management through one interface.